# Jenssegers MongoDB dot notation in fillable

Tags: php, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

I'm trying to get the dot notation working in Jenssegers MongoDB package for Laravel. According this issue it's already been implemented:

[link](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/387)

But it doesn't seem to work in the latest version.

```
protected $fillable = ['title', 'some.data'];
```

Doesn't work. But if I open it all up it works fine.

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

So that works, not sure if this feature is still there or I need to pre filter my fields manually for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested fields are not currently supported in `$fillable`.

Unfortunately this means you have to do it manually.  There are two ways to go:
If you have an embedded `Some` model, you can set $fillable on that, create/fill it with new data, then attach it to the parent model.

If you don't have/want a whole separate model for your subdocument, you would have to define e.g. `$someFillable = ['data'];` and use that to filter your new $some data prior to manually setting it on the model.  You can basically just copy how Eloquent does it in its `fill` method.